# How to get output Select A Select B in PHP 7.4

Tags: php, php-7.4

I have a PHP code

```
<?PHP

  class options{
         public function A(){
              echo "Select A";
         }
         public function B(){
              echo "Select B";
         }
  }


 $opt = new options;

 $opt->B()->A();

?>
```

I need output

============

**Select A Select B**

===========

But I got the output

============

**Select B Select A**

===========

Please Solve my issue.

Comment: _“But I got the output”_ - not with that code you have shown, that should only get you “Select B” - and then a “Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function A() on null in […]”.

Comment: The basis for _method chaining_ to work in the first place, is that each method _returns_ the object instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return class instance in each method. However you didn't specify detailed purpose of this class.

```
class Options
{
    public function A()
    {
        echo "Select A";
        return $this;
    }

    public function B()
    {
        echo "Select B";
        return $this;
    }
}

$opt = new Options;

$opt->A()->B();
```